# What is the advantage of having a logger object instead of using logging?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

With Python and the `logging` library, you can configure logging via a dict `log_config` and

```
logging.config.dictConfig(log_config)
```

The you can log via `logging.info` or create a logger object and use that. What is the advantage of having a logger object?

Comment: In your config, you might have defined different loggers that are picked up by different handlers, so using one particular logger influences various aspects of the log statement: where to log (filename, console), which level and higher is picked up, formatting of the log entry, ...

Comment: Ok, so you want to have logger objects when you have multiple of them. If you only have one, then there is no advantage. Right?

Comment: @MartinThoma there's no advantage in NOT having per-module loggers, cf my answer.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes, there is. It is simpler. You don't have to create a logger object.

Comment: @MartinThoma creating a logger is 36 character long one-liner. If you have a decent editor, you can even configure it to automatically insert this line at the top of all new .py files. Given the benefits of a proper logging configuration vs the pain of looking up relevant infos in gigabytes of line noise, I maintain that there NO advantage in not having proper named loggers.

Answer (score 5):

Loggers form a hierarchy based on their names (using "dotted.path" notation), with the root logger on top. The canonical ways to create loggers is to have one per module, named from the module's `__name__` attribute so if you have a package named "mylib" with modules "utils", "core" and "api", you'll have loggers "mylib", "mylib.utils", "mylib.core" and "mylib.api", where the three last ones are children of "mylib" (which is of course a child of the root logger).

From this you can configure either only the root logger, or more specifically configure the "mylib" logger, or even more specifically configure ie "mylib.api" (note that by default loggers do propagate to their parents). If instead you only use `logging` directly in all your package, you won't be able to customize child loggers per package/module.

The point here is that loggers calls should be decoupled from loggers configuration - library code defines and calls loggers, configuration is the duty of the app using the libraries. The reason is, obviously, that the library author cannot know which apps will use the library code nor how the app's author wants his loggers to be configured. This system gives the app's author (or the sysadmin or whoever is in charge of configuring/deploying the app) full, fine-grained control over logger's configuration. If all your library code only use the root logger then the app author/admin/user cannot have different settings per library/module, and (s)he will hate you for being so intrusive (and let's not talk about how (s)he will feel if your library tries to actually mess with the loggers configuration in any way).

**To make a long story short:** stick to the sane conventions, use `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` in your modules, do **not** try to configure logging in your library code, and your library users will be happy.

EDIT : as you mention in a comment, declaring loggers at the module level can cause problems if the app configures the logging *after* importing your lib *and* does not set `disable_existing_loggers` to False. As far as I'm concerned it's the app's author responsability to either configure logging before import anything else and/or to set `disable_existing_loggers` to False. Configuring the logging first is IMHO a good idea anyway since it will allow library code to log eventual issues at import time...

Comment: What about "[Do not get logger at the module level unless disable_existing_loggers is False](https://fangpenlin.com/posts/2012/08/26/good-logging-practice-in-python/)"?

Comment: The answer is in the same article :  "Since Python2.7, a new argument name “disable_existing_loggers” to fileConfig and dictConfig (as a parameter in schema) is added, by setting it to False, problem mentioned above can be solved"

Comment: According to this article, does that mean I have to defile the logger in each function in the module?!