# Why use logger instead of logging in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

What is the advantage of using a logger instead of just putting logging.**() all over the place?

I have a simple configuration in 2 modules:

```
#one.py

import two
import logging

def do_something():
    logging.info("ONE do something")
    two.do_something()

def main():
    """
    Main function.
    """

    logging.basicConfig(filename="logs/one.log",\
                    level="INFO",\
                    format='%(asctime)s::%(filename)s::%(funcName)s::%(levelname)s::%(message)s',\
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    logging.info('Started ONE #######################')

    do_something() 
    logging.info('Finished')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And

```
#two.py
import logging

def do_something():
    logging.info("TWO do something")

def main():
    """
    Main function.
    """

    logging.basicConfig(filename="logs/two.log",\
                    level="INFO",\
                    format='%(asctime)s::%(filename)s::%(funcName)s::%(levelname)s::%(message)s',\
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    logging.info('Started TWO #######################')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If I run one.py, it will show output like this:

```
2020-11-22 17:49:08::one.py::main::INFO::Started ONE #######################
2020-11-22 17:49:08::one.py::do_something::INFO::ONE do something
2020-11-22 17:49:08::two.py::do_something::INFO::TWO do something
2020-11-22 17:49:08::one.py::main::INFO::Finished
```

If I run module 2, this is the output

```
2020-11-22 17:49:08::two.py::main::INFO::Started TWO #######################
```

As you can see, I am with formatting able to define filename and function name in the output and
the logs from both modules will go to a single file "logs/one.log". This is the behaviour I require.

Is there any advantage to using a logger instead of just defining logging in the main function?

It seems to me that with this basic setup, the logging propagates down to imported modules and maintains the output file and log level setting of the main file I am calling from.

If I define a logger, I would need to pass is as an arg to all functions I am calling, including to imported modules which seems like a massive hassle, unless I am doing something wrong.

Comment: "If I define a logger, I would need to pass is as an arg to all functions I am calling" - no, you don't, you can get the logger from the `logging.getLogger` function, or just use `logging.info`, `logging.debug`, etc. to use the default logger.

Comment: I think I just figured it out? I had to put the logging basicconfig inside the main function of each module and define the logger at the top of the file .. if I defined the the logging.basic at the top of each file, the module that was being imported overrode the settings of the parent module .. I still am not sure why logger should be used instead of logging tho

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48185953/what-is-the-advantage-of-having-a-logger-object-instead-of-using-logging looks like the q is answered here.

Comment: When the logging system starts up, it creates a single root instance of `logging.Logger`. The module-level functions are just wrappers around the root logger's methods (e.g., `logging.info` just calls `logging.root.info()`) as a convenience. Using multiple specific logger objects is far more flexible: you can have different logging configurations for different parts of your code.